# Missing parameter type for expanded function SCALA

Tags: scala

Missing parameter type for expanded function

So my code is :

```
var filter = availableRestaurants.filter(_ => commonOrder.contains(_.cuisine))
```

this is throwing an error called missing parameter type for expanded function at "_.cuisine". I also tried:

```
var filter = availableRestaurants.filter(commonOrder.contains(_.cuisine))
```

`commonOrder` is a list of strings
and `availableRestaurants` is a list of objects that contains a string field called `cuisine`
What would be the best way to rewrite something like this or is this completely illogical?

Answer (score 3):

First, never use `var` in Scala (*unless you have to*). Better use `val`.

```
var filter = availableRestaurants.filter(_ => commonOrder.contains(_.cuisine))
```

This is given the `filter` function an anonymous function which discards its first argument. But you want to use the argument for the contains check. (the `_` in a function call is special, the second one does not refer to the first)

The reason for the error is that the `commonOrder.contains(_.cuisine)` part needs to be (eta) expanded first, ie. the method call needs to be converted to a function since `filter` expects a function. But without knowing what `_` stands for, and hence what the type of `_.cuisine` is, this fails.

Do it like this:

```
val filter = availableRestaurants.filter(r => commonOrder.contains(r.cuisine))
```

Or, expand the method into a function manually beforehand:

```
val containsCuisine = (r: Restaurant) => commonOrder.contains(r.cuisine)
val filter = availableRestaurants.filter(containsCuisine)
```

Or, to use composition, similar to what you can do with lenses:

```
val cuisineOf = (r: Restaurant) => r.cuisine // re-usable
val filter = availableRestaurants.filter(cuisineOf andThen commonOrder.contains)
```